# How Can I Extract Predictions from A Softmax Layer on Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction, softmax, categorization

I'm trying to extract predictions, use predictions in calculating accuracy/precision/recall/F1 and prediction probability. I know I have 10 output classes therefore I can't calculate precision per see but I will be doing all these in other models moreover I'd like to be able to extract prediction probabilities. My model is as follows. I've checked GitHub and StackOverflow however I have yet to find a way to extract those properties. Most of the answers come close but never answer what I needed. I've used some low epoch numbers there in order to check out model fast and keep the output screen less crowded.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import fully_connected

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home="data/mnist/")
lb = LabelBinarizer().fit(mnist.target)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(mnist.data, lb.transform(mnist.target), train_size=0.9, test_size=0.1)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None, 10))

lOne = fully_connected(inputs=X, num_outputs=100, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)
logits = fully_connected(inputs=lOne, num_outputs=10, activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax)

pred = logits
acc = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=y, predictions=pred)

loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits=logits, onehot_labels=y)
trainOP = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

import numpy as np
bSize = 100
batches = int(np.floor(X_train.shape[0]/bSize)+1)
def batcher(dSet, bNum):
    return(dSet[bSize*(bNum-1):bSize*(bNum)])

epochs = 2
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(0, epochs):
        for batch in range(1, batches):
            X_batch = batcher(X_train, batch)
            y_batch = batcher(y_train, batch)
            sess.run(trainOP, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        lossVal = sess.run([loss], feed_dict={X: X_test, y: y_test})
        print(lossVal)


    sess.close()
```

Comment: If you are asking how to run your model to predict on some input, you need to save the model to a checkpoint file, create a new script that loads the model and run it ones with the input you pass (e.g. on the CLI). There are many tutorials. It is is now called “inference” or simply running the (trained) model.

Comment: I do not need to save/load model to make predictions. I just can't make predictions, calling  logits bring me a layer instead of predictions. I know question is simple however question is precise as well and I don't have anyone to ask. I've been spending best of my 5 hours on this simple problem. I don't know how to fetch results from the model. I can save and load model with no problem.

Comment: @SalihF.Canpolat 
In SO you should not edit the title to indicate that you have solved your problem, you must mark as correct the answer that you did, if you have solved it yourself then I invite you to publish the answer and mark it as correct

Comment: @eyllanesc I have done so now and I'll be able to mark it as correct in 2 hours. Thanks for the pointers. I normally do not ask on Stackoverflow unless I'm absolutely forced to do so.

Comment: @SalihF.Canpolat 
The questions and answers in SO should not only serve you but the entire community so if you delete many things no one will understand or be useful, I recommend reading [ask] and [answer], consider SO as a book of questions and answers, it would not be annoying to answer the same question many times, that is why we want quality questions and answers that help the community and save us time.

Answer (score 3):

The code shared in the question covers training, but not "using" (infering) with the resulting model.

Two issues:

- The trained model is not serialized, so future runs will run on an *untrained* model, and predict whatever their initialization tells them to. Hence a [question comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50537777/how-can-i-extract-predictions-from-a-softmax-layer-on-tensorflow/50539238#comment88087647_50537777) suggesting to save the trained model, and restore it when predicting.
- The logits are the output of a SoftMax function. A common way to get a class from logits is to select the highest value in the tensor (here a vector).

With TensorFlow, the last point can be done with [`tf.argmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax) ("Returns the index with the largest value across axes of a tensor."):

```
tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1)
```

All in all, the question's code covers only partially the [MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) from the TensorFlow team. Perhaps more pointers there if you get stuck with this code.

Comment: I've fixed the code, and the question. I was trying to extract softmax probabilities and managed to do it with `tf.nn.softmax(logits)` I still don't get why are we inclined to do argmax instead of going one hot. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: By erasing the original question and replacing everything with your solution is confusing. No one can understand what the problem was, and if the answer actually helps. And yes, one-hot encoding helps too—there can be several answers to the same problem. It would be great if you could restore your original question, and add your solution (either as an update at the end of the question, or an answer to your own question).

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing in case anyone may stumble upon this particular case. I've built a network following basic MNIST examples, I've used `tf.nn.softmax` in the final layer and expected to get results from said layer. It looks like I need to use softmax function again to get the results from a layer such as `yPred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)` with `logits` being the name of the output layer. I'm adding fixed code below.

I can add a line to save the model, load it later on and made predictions on saved model. Since this is just an example for me building the model, I've omitted the saving part.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import fully_connected

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home="data/mnist/")
lb = LabelBinarizer().fit(mnist.target)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(mnist.data, lb.transform(mnist.target), train_size=0.9, test_size=0.1, stratify = mnist.target, random_state=42)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None, 10))


lOne = fully_connected(inputs=X, num_outputs=100, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)
lTwo = fully_connected(inputs=lOne, num_outputs=100, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)
logits = fully_connected(inputs=lTwo, num_outputs=10, activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax)

pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
acc_bool = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
acc_Num = tf.cast(acc_bool, tf.float32)
acc_Mean = tf.reduce_mean(acc_Num)

loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits=logits, onehot_labels=y)
trainOP = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)


import numpy as np
bSize = 1024
batches = int(np.floor(X_train.shape[0]/bSize)+1)
def batcher(dSet, bNum):
    return(dSet[bSize*(bNum-1):bSize*(bNum)])



epochs = 250
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
trainA = []
testA = []

with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(init)
for epoch in range(0, epochs):
    for batch in range(1, batches):
        X_batch = batcher(X_train, batch)
        y_batch = batcher(y_train, batch)
        sess.run(trainOP, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
    if epoch % 25 == 1:
        trainLoss, trainAcc = sess.run([loss, acc_Mean], feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
        testLoss, testAcc = sess.run([loss, acc_Mean], feed_dict={X: X_test, y: y_test})
        yPred = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={X: X_test[0].reshape(1,-1), y: y_test[0].reshape(1,-1)})
        print(yPred)

sess.close()
```